# Python (v2.7) requires to install plugins to create media files of the following type: Vorbis encoder

Tags: python, music-player

This is the message I get when I try to rip a cd from any player. I usually use the stock Rhythmbox but have tried others to no avail. I have just updated to 12.10 from 12.04 and I had no problems in 12.04. I have read the other posts and have switched to the Main Server in the Software Sources menu. I have installed Ubuntu Restricted Extras. Nothing seems to help. I would appreciate any help.

"Python (v2.7) requires to install plugins to create media files of the following type: Vorbis encoder"

Thanks!

Comment: And i have used the command line to install python. Still didn't help.

Answer (score 12):

Same thing happened to me, but I finally get some clues in this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1965432).

Turns out that problems are caused by the **config** file:

```
sudo gvim /usr/share/rhythmbox/rhythmbox.gep
```

Delete or comment the "preset" line as follow

```
[profile-oggvorbis]
name = oggvorbis
description = Ogg Vorbis
format = application/ogg
type = container

[streamprofile-oggvorbis-1]
parent = oggvorbis
type = audio

#preset = rhythmbox-custom-settings

format = audio/x-vorbis
presence = 1
```

and, voila, restart your Rhythmbox, problem solved.

Comment: works but you have to comment several present lines

Answer (score 5):

This answer from ubuntu forum solve the problem esasily:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2077423

> The "Install additional software required to use this format" message
>   seen for vorbis encoding is a bug. All needed libraries are installed
>   by default, as is vorbis encoding in RB. (if you went ahead it would
>   have used the 'ubuntu default'
>
> To get the message to disappear you have to pick ' Custom Setting" &
>   set a quality value, then close & open RB (Default is gnome default of
>   3 Ubuntu is a quality of 6 or you can set as desired, higher the
>   better quality

Answer (score 2):

I have gotten the same error on 12.10 and have not found a fix, but have a workaround.  Install Sound Juicer and it will extract with no error, then open Rhythmbox and it will import the information after a couple of seconds.  Not perfect, but it works for me.

Comment: That's what I started to do but 12.10 just had too many bugs and issues on my Dell Latitude and I ultimately unistalled it and put 12.04 back on. Works much better now :)