# How do I install python2.7 in order to play music in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, python-2.7

When I try to play music in Rhythmbox, it's asking me to install python 2.7.

1. May I know the links and process to download and install it?
2. Also please let me know the other softwares to update.
3. When I try to type `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` in the terminal, it's throwing an error:  *Couldn't find any extras.*

Can any one please resolve this issue?

Comment: You might be having other more serious issues if Rhythmbox is asking for Python and apt-get throws that error with that package. What version of Ubuntu did you install and what editing/installing/removing/upgrading did you do before noticing the Rhythmbox issue?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204293/python-v2-7-requires-to-install-plugins-to-create-media-files-of-the-following):

Which is solved [here.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2077423)

If that doesn't work, you could try:

```
sudo apt-get install python
```